# How to change the location of perl?

Tags: perl

I tried to upgrade the perl version from 5.22.1 to 5.26. But unfortunately it installed at /usr/local/bin
But it supposed to be in /usr/bin

I have both versions of perl in system. When I am trying to use bioperl modules, it was saying can't find module, install. But in actual I had all required modules. I worked with those modules earlier. How can I rectify this problem.

In actual what I did was

```
cp perl 5.26.0
./Configure -de -Desuches
make
make tests
make install
```

I did with root access

When I type

```
which perl
```

It was showing

```
usr/local/bin/perl
```

And `cpan` installed at

```
usr/local/lib/cpan
```

Why it happened?

Comment: Do not overrwrite `/usr/bin/perl`!!!! You'll mess up your system

Comment: Thanks sure..I am not going to overwrite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But it supposed to be in /usr/bin

It's a bad idea to overwrite the system installation of Perl. Half to most of the other installed software that is depending on that Perl version will break. If you're particularly unlucky, you'll break a low-level system tool, and you'll end up in a situation where the system is in such a bad condition that you cannot easily recover from except by a full reinstall.

> When I type `which perl` It was showing `usr/local/bin/perl` And cpan installed at `usr/local/lib/cpan` Why it happened?

Because the default [installation prefix](http://search.cpan.org/~shay/perl-5.24.2/INSTALL#Installation_prefix) is `/usr/local`. It can be changed in the `./Configure` step.

> How can I rectify this problem.

The simple (but slightly tedious) way is to always use the full paths. So installing BioPerl is:

```
/usr/local/lib/cpan Bio::Perl
```

… the shebang to your own Perl programs is

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
```

etc.

This works because installed modules will go into your custom Perl's library path, and your custom Perl's executable knows how to find them.

Comment: Somehow I managed to remove my newer version of perl but I would like to use perl 5.26 for some programming purpose.. is there anyway to update my perl or if any suggestion also will helps me.

Answer (score 2):

I think using a tool like [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/) or [plenv](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/TOKUHIROM/App-plenv-v1.4.0/bin/plenv) is safer and provides you a lot of features. For example, you can install different versions of Perl and use whatever you want, without collisions between installations.

It is not a good idea to change the system perl.

Comment: This. Plenty of system-installed scripts are likely to use the system-wide perl. they aren't known to work on whatever version you might swap it with.